# Disable elements on pc build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game that I want to run on both pc and android. For android, I have a joystick that allows the player to move however on the pc you can just use WASD. Is there a way to disable a UI element on just the pc version of the game so the joystick doesn't appear on the pc version?

**e.g**

```
if(android build)
{
   Disable UI element 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity provides list of `#define` directives - available at [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

Those directives allows to run pre-processor, which provide some changes to the code right before compilation/build (it is called pre-processor directives). It can optimize the code for specific platform or similar workflow/conditions. Check [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) for more details.

For your case with android, use directive `UNITY_ANDROID` (Unity automatically defines this directive, that is why you can use it). In code:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    callFuncForAndroid();
#else
    callNonAndroidFunc();
#endif
```